# Save a Bookmark which can open 2 URLs one after another

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarks

Is it possible to save a bookmark with 2 URLs ? Upon clicking on the bookmark, the first URL should be opened first and after a brief pause the second URL is opened in the same window.

E.g. First I want to open the link https://stackoverflow.com/ and after 5 seconds I want to open 2nd URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask automatically in the same window.

I know we can directly open the 2nd URL but I have some dependency on 1st URL hence don't want to skip it.

Comment: Nope.  Not possible.  It's up to the browser to do that, not the server.

Comment: you probably need a [bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591257/how-do-i-create-a-bookmarklet) making calls to `window.open('https://www.example.com', '_blank');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [Bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)

> A bookmarklet is a bookmark stored in a web browser that contains
> JavaScript commands that add new features to the browser. They are
> stored as the URL of a bookmark in a web browser or as a hyperlink on
> a web page. Bookmarklets are usually small snippets of JavaScript
> executed when user clicks on them.

In Javascript you may use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to visit urls.

By specifying `_blank` as the [target keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#target)

> _blank: usually a new tab, but users can configure browsers to open a new window instead.

To create one, add a new bookmark pasting a code like this in the URL field:

```
javascript:(function() {
    window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', '_blank');
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask', '_blank');
    }, 5000);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you Diego. That served my purpose. I'm just thinking of adding one more step. My landing page is a pop up where we have 2 options to select - "OK" and "Cancel". Is there a possibility to click on "OK" automatically ?

Comment: and why not also autofilling the credit card and press send money? The point is I don't know if you have the returned window object in terms of interaction with its own dom. You have to see yourself and eventually ask on SO about how to do specific things in js

Comment: Agreed. Thank you. I don't know ABC of javascript but in the process of learning. Cheers!